# Ajax call to webservice, which returns HTML failing to apply CSS

Tags: jquery, vb.net, css, webmethod

I have an ajax call to a webservice to return HTML like this on my page.

```
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="Styles/Style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function () {
       $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         url: "WebServices/wsHTML.asmx/getHTML",
         data: "{'sDisplayStyle': '" + strDisplayStyle+ "'}",
         dataType: "json",
         global: false,
         async: false,
         success: function (sHTML) {
            insertContent(sHTML.d);
         },
         error: function (sHTML) {
            alert("Error");
         }
      });

      function insertDisplay(sHTML) {
         var parent = $("#display_style");
         parent.append(sHTML);
      };
    };
    </script>
</head>
 <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <div id="display_style">  <%-- Insert html here --%>

      </div>
    </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

The problem is that the stylesheet is not being applied. I have tried appending the stylesheet with no luck. If I just paste the HTML directly into the page it works fine so the CSS path is good.

Here is the webMethod:

```
Public Function getHTML(byval sDisplayStyle As String) As String
    Dim sHTML As String = "<div id='MakeMeGreen'>"
    sHTML = sHTML + "</div>"
    Return sHTML
End Function
```

Everything works great, but the CSS. Anyone have any tips I am stumped?

Comment: What CSS are you expecting to be applied, you're appending a div with no content inside it.

Comment: I took out the html code as it has some sensitive information. Lets just say the CSS will make the div a green square. It's not even doing that.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling method `insertContent()` on success.

There's no method named that. Perhaps you meant `insertDisplay()`?

Comment: Oops sorry, I messed up pasting. I do call insertDisplay. The HTML is properly returned and displayed. The stylesheet is just failing.

Comment: Okay it is running an old version of the web method apparently. I have tried clearing the cache and even rebooting, but the inner html error is referring to something that was taken out of the function a while back. How can I get it to run the new web method?